# difference in "if" and "cond" in Scheme

Tags: scheme, lisp

I'm learning Berkeley CS61A using Scheme. `pigl` function is used to introduce recursion and the sample code is as follows

```lisp
(define (pigl wd)
  (if (pl-done? wd) 
    (word wd 'ay)
    (pigl (word (bf wd) (first wd))) ) )
```

I tried to change `if` to`cond` expression, the modified code is as follows

```
(define (pigl2 wd)
  (cond ((pl-done? wd) (word wd 'ay))
      (else pigl2 (word (bf wd) (first wd))) ) )
```

Based on my understanding of the interpretation of `if` and `cond` in SICP, I think these two procedures should be equivalent. However `pigl2` didn't work that it gave `'ab` for input `'ba` and the correct answer is `abay`.

I don’t know if I misunderstood the evaluation rules of `if` and `cond` or if I made any other stupid mistakes. Please help me, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is your code, commented to highlight the problem:

```
(define (pigl2 wd)
  (cond ((pl-done? wd) (word wd 'ay))
      (else
       pigl2 ; this line does nothing at all
       (word (bf wd) (first wd))))) ; return result of calling `word`
```

You forgot to actually *call* `pigl2`: it's missing the surrounding brackets! This should fix the problem:

```
(define (pigl2 wd)
  (cond ((pl-done? wd) (word wd 'ay))
        (else (pigl2 (word (bf wd) (first wd))))))
```

Comment: I was too careless. Thanks for your reply!